# Conditional Partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table (Employee_Training) that has the following columns:

- Employee_Number
- Course_ID
- Date_Completed

I have this query that I use to show training, and it filters out the duplicate Date_Completed, only showing the most recent date:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY t.Course_ID, t.Employee_Number 
            ORDER BY t.Date_Completed DESC) AS rank
        FROM Employee_Training t) x
WHERE x.rank = 1
```

Is there any way to format this query not to apply the partition to a specific Course_ID, say like 1000004? I would want to see all the rows where Course_ID = 1000004.

Here is some sample data:

Just using a select all on that table:

```
557 | 1000002 | 2014-11-18
557 | 1000002 | 2009-7-6
557 | 1000004 | 2011-1-15
557 | 1000004 | 2005-9-22
557 | 1000004 | 2004-4-17
557 | 1000010 | 2014-6-10
557 | 1000010 | 2013-6-09
557 | 1000010 | 2012-6-10
```

Using my original query I get these results:

```
557 | 1000002 | 2014-11-18
557 | 1000004 | 2011-1-15
557 | 1000010 | 2014-6-10
```

What I would like to see (Only the 1000004 not being filtered out):

```
557 | 1000002 | 2014-11-18
557 | 1000004 | 2011-1-15
557 | 1000004 | 2005-9-22
557 | 1000004 | 2004-4-17
557 | 1000010 | 2014-6-10
```

Thank you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could exclude them from you're row_number partition and union them on at end.

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY t.Course_ID, t.Employee_Number 
            ORDER BY t.Date_Completed DESC) AS rank
        FROM Employee_Training t
       WHERE course_id!=1000004) x
WHERE x.rank = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT t.*,1 as rank
        FROM Employee_Training t
        WHERE course_id=1000004
```